# Pandas: cross dataset column matching

Tags: python, pandas

There are multiple datasets and I would like to find out how they potentially connected with each other. E.g. if string columns in datasets A and B have lots of values in common, that might be a link. Is it possible to do this kind of analysis automatically?

Comment: use `pandas.merge` to do a database-style join

Comment: @PaulH I don't want to make a join. I would like to discover on which columns to join.

Comment: start digging with `pandas.Series.unique`

Answer (score 0):

you could always make them into dataframes and check that way. Might be slow depending on size of your data. But this is a very basic way and the code below creates extra dataframes for learning purposes, not the best code but I wanted you to see the progression.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [np.NaN,np.NaN,3,4,5,5,3,1,5,np.NaN], 
                    'B' : [1,0,3,5,0,0,np.NaN,9,0,0], 
                    'C' : ['Pharmacy of IDAHO','Access medicare arkansas','NJ Pharmacy','Idaho Rx','CA Herbals','Florida Pharma','AK RX','Ohio Drugs','PA Rx','USA Pharma'], 
                    'D' : [123456,123456,1234567,12345678,12345,12345,12345678,123456789,1234567,np.NaN],
                    'E' : ['Assign','Unassign','Assign','Ugly','Appreciate','Undo','Assign','Unicycle','Assign','Unicorn',]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [np.NaN,np.NaN,3,4,5,5,3,1,5,np.NaN], 
                    'B' : [1,0,3,5,0,0,np.NaN,9,0,0], 
                    'C' : ['Pharmacy of IDAHO','Arkansas','NJ Pharmacy','Idaho Rockies?','CA Herbals','blah blah','AK RX','test_test','PA Rx','USA4Lyfe'], 
                    'D' : [123456,123456,1234567,12345678,12345,12345,12345678,123456789,1234567,np.NaN]})
#Creates a Column in DF2 If Matching
df2['Values']= df['C'] == df2['C']
#Creates another dataframe where the values are only True
df3 = df2[df2['Values']== True]
#Prints the length of the DataFrame which actually gives you the amount of common values
print("There are",len(df3), "Occurences")
```

output:
`There are  5 Occurences`